# X-compiling on Linux with NDK/clang++ and boost to Android

Tags: android, c++, linux, boost

I have developed a library that wraps [svg++](https://github.com/svgpp/svgpp).
svg++ is a header only library that utilises parts of boost, and  these parts it pulls in are also header files only.
It does not require linking with any boost pre-built binaries.

I have built my library for Linux and for Windows.
I need to also x-compile to Android.

Question:
Seeing as I use only boost headers, should I be able to x-compile natively from Linux to Android using the NDK and a local Linux install of boost?

Of course I have tried this, but clang++ seems for all intents and purposes not to look in /usr/include.

```bash
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/svgpp-source.dir/src/svgparser.cpp.o 
FAILED: CMakeFiles/svgpp-source.dir/src/svgparser.cpp.o  
/home/iwarv/AndroidSDK/ndk/22.1.7171670/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ --target=aarch64-none-linux-android22 -I/home/iwarv/git/svgpp-source/include -I/home/iwarv/git/svgpp-source/extern/svgpp/include -I/home/iwarv/git/svgpp-source/extern/svgpp/third_party/rapidxml_ns -funwind-tables -no-canonical-prefixes -fexceptions -frtti -stdlib=libc++ -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -fPIC -std=gnu++17 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/svgpp-source.dir/src/svgparser.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/svgpp-source.dir/src/svgparser.cpp.o -o CMakeFiles/svgpp-source.dir/src/svgparser.cpp.o -c /home/iwarv/git/svgpp-source/src/svgparser.cpp 
In file included from /home/iwarv/git/svgpp-source/src/svgparser.cpp:4: 
In file included from /home/iwarv/git/svgpp-source/extern/svgpp/include/svgpp/policy/xml/rapidxml_ns.hpp:12: 
In file included from /home/iwarv/git/svgpp-source/extern/svgpp/include/svgpp/definitions.hpp:12: 
/home/iwarv/git/svgpp-source/extern/svgpp/include/svgpp/utility/boost_parameter_fixed.hpp:10:10: fatal error: 'boost/version.hpp' file not found 
#include <boost/version.hpp>
```

It's my understanding that a compiler would by default look in /usr/include and does not require it to be told through `-I`

Yet if I manually run the above command and explicitly add `-I/usr/include` then I get past this compilation error.

And if I run:

```bash
~/AndroidSDK/ndk/22.1.7171670/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ -v -E -
```

The output contains:

```bash
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /home/iwarv/AndroidSDK/ndk/22.1.7171670/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/11.0.5/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
```

Perhaps what I try to do here cannot be done. But it would be nice to learn why.

### Edit

I can confirm that boost headers are installed to /usr/include

```bash
find /usr/include -name version.hpp
... multiple files including...
/usr/include/boost/version.hpp
```

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up just downloading boost from the website and installing it into my home directory.

All it needed then was to point `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` and `Boost_INCLUDE_DIR` at this directory and everything built just fine.

On all platforms.